# How to manage size of image assets in mobile apps with ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

Due to screen density of iPhone, image assets are developed larger. So, when specifying the icons and images to Flex components takes this form.

```
<s:ViewNavigator id="tab1" label="Tab1 width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.Tab1">
        <s:icon>
            <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource source160dpi="@Embed('assets/tabIcon.png')"/>
        </s:icon>
</s:ViewNavigator>
```

Flex of course renders this correctly and adjusts the size to what it should be.

However, when I load images myself, they appear blown up as they would appear double in size.

This is how I use it when overriding the tab bar.

```
public class TabbedViewNavigatorTabBarSkin extends ButtonBarSkin
{

    [Embed (source="/assets/tabBar.png" )]
    private var TabBarPng:Class;

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        var bgb:Bitmap = new TabBarPng() ;

        addChild(bgb);
    }
}
```

This is when the image appears blown up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have applicationDPI set, if so Flex will scale everything based on the applicationDPI/runtime actual DPI.  So if the applicationDPI is lower than the actual runtime DPI it will scale up your components.  In the first case you're using a class that specifically picks which image to use based on what you specify and what the runtime DPI is (and I imagine does no further scaling).  The other case you're just telling it to use a Bitmap but not specifying that it is already scaled appropriately... can't u just use a MultiDPIBitmapSource and set it's source160dpi=new TabBarPng()?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. Could you please post this bit of code? If it works I'm more than happy to use it, it looks like a good approach. And no, I didn't set the applicationDPI anywhere specifically. My images are 72ppi and retina size.

Comment: If you take out the applicationDPI does it still scale your Bitmap to be too large?  If not you may want to just leave that property turned off.  What it will do for you is scale statically set width/height properties based on the applicationDPI vs the run-time DPI so like a 100 px box on a screen with twice the resolution will end up being a 200 px box in reality even though it will report a width of 100.  I'll see if I can find an easy way to test this out with the demo mobile app I have sitting around.

Comment: It scales correctly when removing the applicationDPI property. But what will be the implication of this, I guess it does have a purpose other than screwing loaded images.

Comment: haha, yah so the intention is that if you set an applicationDPI then it will adjust the values for drawing based on the property versus runtime DPI, sorry I know I'm repeating myself but really that's the best I can explain it.  I answered another similar question recently, it's the only reason I know.  On my Galaxy Nexus if I set the applicationDPI in an app to 160, since my screen density is 320 it doubles the size of everything, this way if I designed assuming a 160DPI screen and someone has higher my objects will be the right visual size on their screen too

Comment: Far more on it here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html

Comment: Thanks for all this, but now back to square 1, if I do set the DPI, then how to control the size of images loaded with AS as Class and displayed as Bitmap? Btw, why don't you answer so I can upvote you.

Comment: sure I'll give it a couple of shots, gotta make myself a png first :) and I'll let you know how it plays out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think what you're trying to get it to do can be achieved with the following code, this is basically going to negate the work done internally to scale the asset based on the screen size, while allowing it to scale other components based on the DPI, I'm not sure exactly how this will play out in practice.

```
        import mx.core.mx_internal;
```

...

```
        var bgb : Bitmap = new TabBarPng();
        bgb.scaleX = 1 / systemManager.mx_internal::densityScale;
        bgb.scaleY = 1 / systemManager.mx_internal::densityScale;
```

or another possibility I think is:

```
        var mul : MultiDPIBitmapSource = new MultiDPIBitmapSource();
        mul.source160dpi = new TabBarPng();

        var bgb : BitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bgb.source = mul;

        var gr : Graphic = new Graphic();
        gr.width = 100 / systemManager.mx_internal::densityScale; //not sure if you'd want densityScale being applied here or what?  Same below just a matter of testing on more devices
        gr.height = 100 / systemManager.mx_internal::densityScale;
        gr.addElement(bgb)
        addChild(gr);
```

[From MultiDPIBitmapSource API doc]

This class provides a list of bitmaps for various runtime densities. It is supplied as the source to BitmapImage or Image and as the icon of a Button. The components will use the Application.runtimeDPI to choose which image to display.

I think this documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html

is probably still the clearest explanation you'll find though it's not entirely clear how this will affect the application at run-time on different devices.  The best option is to just test on as many devices as you can (or need to support).

Comment: Thanks for taking a dive into this. Looks like another glaring slopiness in Flex design. I see I will have to do without DPI manager and test more on devices.

Comment: applicationDPI can only be set in MXML.